# Why won't my domain server (2008 R2) sync with external time service correctly?

Tags: windows-server-2008, time-synchronization

I have configured my PDC (windows 2008 R2) to sync with external time source uk.pool.ntp.org and followed all the instructions to the letter which are set out here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/industry_insiders/archive/2006/08/29/w32-tm-service.aspx

but for some reason it always remains 5-6mins faster than the correct time. When I query the value against the peers it shows this:

```
  C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /peers
#Peers: 1

Peer: uk.pool.ntp.org,0x1
State: Active
Time Remaining: 732.9759988s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 2 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
PeerPoll Interval: 10 (1024s)
HostPoll Interval: 10 (1024s)

C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /monitor /computers:uk.pool.ntp.org
uk.pool.ntp.org[82.219.4.30:123]:
    ICMP: 15ms delay
    NTP: -339.9182573s offset from local clock
        RefID: ntp2.linx.net [195.66.241.10]
        Stratum: 2

Warning:
Reverse name resolution is best effort. It may not be
correct since RefID field in time packets differs across
NTP implementations and may not be using IP addresses.
```

can anyone tell me why this is so? It's driving me mad!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pauska I tried to but can't for another 8 hours, as I don't have 100 points. Vote me up and I'll do it quicker :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK So after loads of looking and checking and reconfiguring, I had a massive AH HAAH! moment:

This machine is running as a virtual server! 
Hyper-V has a time synchronization integration service.
The Hyper-V Host machine upon checking had the wrong time!

going to settings on the hyper-v manager for this domain server and unchecking the time synchronisation under management -> integration services and then applying, immeadiately fixed the issue!

I really hope this helps someone.